# How can I work around warning C4505 in third party libraries?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, crypto++

I've got a project that uses Crypto++ for a few hashing functions. Recently, I decided to clean things up a bit and use warning level 4 on MSVC++.

Here's what my source looks like:

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4100) //Unreferenced formal parameter
#pragma warning(disable: 4244) //Conversion, possible loss of data
#pragma warning(disable: 4512) //Assignment operator could not be generated
#pragma warning(disable: 4127) //Conditional expression is constant
#pragma warning(disable: 4505) //Unreferenced local function has been removed
#define CRYPTOPP_ENABLE_NAMESPACE_WEAK 1
#include <cryptopp/md5.h>
#include <cryptopp/sha.h>
#pragma warning(pop)
```

Despite `disable: 4505`, I still get this warning:

```
c:\cppdev\cryptopp561\cryptopp\misc.h(548): warning C4505: 'CryptoPP::StringNarrow' : unreferenced local function has been removed
```

and my project does not build.

How can I work around this? Basically, I'd just like to disable the warning for third party code; I don't want to be editing cryptopp itself to fix the error if I can avoid doing so.

Comment: Warnings should not stop you from building, right?

Comment: @tylo42: many projects set "treat warnings as errors" option

Comment: @Vlad: thanks, I was not aware of that option.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The compiler can only determine unreferenced functions after it finished parsing the compiled source file. Move the corresponding `#pragma disable` out of the push/pop scope so it will still be in effect at the end of the file:

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4100) //Unreferenced formal parameter
#pragma warning(disable: 4244) //Conversion, possible loss of data
#pragma warning(disable: 4512) //Assignment operator could not be generated
#pragma warning(disable: 4127) //Conditional expression is constant
#define CRYPTOPP_ENABLE_NAMESPACE_WEAK 1
#include <cryptopp/md5.h>
#include <cryptopp/sha.h>
#pragma warning(pop)
#pragma warning(disable: 4505) //Unreferenced local function has been removed
```

Comment: This disables the warning for my code, not just the third party code.

Comment: @BillyONeal: Yes, and he's saying that it's simply going to be all or nothing, because the compiler won't trigger this warning until after the code is compiled.

Comment: According to MS this can't be done using the pragma:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947783

In this particular case you can silence the compiler this way - but this won't work all over the place probably:

void useUnreferenced()
{
 void* dummyReferenceStringNarrow = CryptoPP::StringNarrow;
 (void)dummyReferenceStringNarrow ;
}

Comment: This is correct.  There are ways to isolate crappy third party code, #include is not one of them.

Comment: @Hans: Okay, then what do you propose? The implementations I can isolate into their own compilation domains. The headers I cannot.

Comment: An extra level of indirection solves every problem.  That's an old horse that's appropriate here, write a wrapper.

Comment: @Tobiesque : the link you posted is now broken. Can you provide an updated one? Thnx

Comment: @HansPassant - I tried your suggestion, but it does not work for me. Do you mean having an intermediate header file which includes, e.g., <cryptopp/md5.h>? I tried with a chain of two such headers without improvements.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need a few hashing functions, create a separate source file with 4505 disabled to include the crapto headers and write your own header file to define the function prototypes you use.

Comment: Lol @ crapto. Perhaps I should look around for a better md5 + sha library.