# C - best practice for casting a void* to int, kernel

Tags: c, casting, linux-kernel, int, void-pointers

I'm writing a module for Linux kernel, and I want to store a `int` value in the file private data.

Essentially, what I do is: `file->private_data = (void*) x`
where x is some `int` value.

Now, I want to access the int back as a value.

Using `int val = (int) file->private_data` gives out a `cast from pointer to integer of different size` warning during compilation, which is reasonable since it may cause problems on a 64bit systems.

I also cannot use `uintptr_t` since I'm working in kernel and I do not have access to libraries.

Using `double` seems inappropriate.

My question is: What should be the best practice to do so?

Comment: IMHO, best practice would be to prevent such things. I remember that I saw X11 callbacks (long long ago - I believe even in the O'Reilly X books) where the callback client data pointer was abused to provide an `int` - accessed via similar hackish casting. (That people probably tried to come around allocation/storage effort for client data this way.) May be, there might be even a rule that a pointer has at least `sizeof (int)` but I would not bet my house for it... (though it is surely true for Intel x86). Btw. to come around the warning `int val = (int)(ssize_t)file->private_data;` might help.

Comment: @Fredrik: "*you are storing the value wrong*" No, as the OP does not want to store an address. But (misuse) the pointer to store an integer.

Comment: Related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/290574/35384

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6825640/694576

Comment: FIrst question is can you make sure that a `void *` can hold all the possible values of your int parameter on all architectures you target? As you a writing a **Linux** kernel module wide portability is not really a concern. If the answer is yes, then the conversion is implementation dependent according to the standard, and any *normal* implementation will ensure that casting forth and back will return original value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In gcc world (Linux kernel is compiled by gcc), `long` (or `unsigned long`) has the the same size as a pointer. You may use this feature when convert pointers to integer and back:

```
// store
file->private_data = (void*)(long) x;
// load
int val = (int) (long) file->private_data;
```

---

**Note**: This answer addresses specifically **Linux kernel** programming.

For *user-space application* suggested approach could be treated as a *bad practice*, or simply being *wrong*.

Comment: thanks, I used a casting through (ssize_t) at the end and it worked, long seems to be ok as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate how come you got yourself into a situation where storing an int there is reasonable?

Normally this would be a pointer to a reference-counted object. In particular, if you are using that to look up another object, this very field should probably just point to that object.