# Is it possible to turn off compiler warnings?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

If i choose
Level warning(all)
**/Wall**

Studio show many warnings from this files:

```
wchar.h
math.h
xmemory0
xstring
```

Example:

**code**:

```
std::cout << "\n\n";
```

**compiler**:

*ios(116): warning C4710: std::string std::_Generic_error_category::message(int) const:*

Maybe there are some macroses, some like this?

```
#define start_warnings
#undef start_warnings
```

Comment: you should tell us a bit more, like the compiler version and full compile command, the full warning message etc. Yes, there are ways to suppress warnings, but this is usually not a good idea.

Comment: This may help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159348/disable-single-warning-error

Comment: I *think* OP wants to disable warnings for external headers, which is [possible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e.aspx).

Comment: Visual Studio Wall isn't helpful for general development, unlike gcc Wall. Use level 4

Comment: It is possible, but you should not do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Visual Studio `/Wall` enables some very obscure warnings. They can be useful, such as locating structures with padding bytes, but in general are overkill and the system headers are not designed to be warning-free at this level. Use `/W4` instead.

See `#pragma warning` if you do need to adjust the level or enable/disable specific warnings.