# MSVS 2015 express error C4146 - unary minus operator applied to unsigned type

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

is there a way to disable error C4146 in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 - express edition? I tried to set "Treat warnings as errors" option to no, however MSVC still treats C4146 as error. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Do you really want `-some_unsigned_var` in your code?  Do you realize that it will not be a negative number?

Comment: It's part of NTL library code

Comment: I think it is legal code and it should be treated as warning or not?

Comment: It's perfectly legal and has well-defined effects - but they aren't necessarily what's expected. The warning is there because this is a fairly unusual operation. Have you tried `#pragma warning`? (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159348/disable-single-warning-error)

Comment: Looks like it gets turned on at warning level 2: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kh09110.aspx

Comment: There's a good chance you were using /sdl (this is the project wizard's default).  You'd need to disable it in addition to treat-warnings-as-errors

Answer (score 17):

"SDL checks" is set to to "Yes (/sdl)" by default settings for a new Microsoft Visual Studio Community Edition project. This turns certain "security relevant" warnings into errors. Set the parameter to "No (/sdl-)", to turn them back to warnings.

See Microsoft documentation on "SDL Check", currently [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj161081.aspx).

Edit: The question was already answered in comments, but I missed the answer because of the long thread.

Comment: Where can I disable SDL (set the parameter to No) because I'm getting the same error? Thank you!

Comment: It's under Project / Properties / C/C++ / General / SDL Checks

Comment: Found it! Thank you!