# GMP Library error C4416 unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned

Tags: c, visual-c++, g++, gmp

I have tried to install the GMP Library on Visual C++ for coding with big integers. The installation is good, I've used "make check" to test the gmp and everything is fine. But when I tried to build any simple code, it gives an error:

```
 "C4416 unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned    TestGMP h:\gmp\include\gmp.h    2197"
```

Apparently, this error comes from the header file itself. I have tried to solve this bug a whole day but no result. I've tried re-install, install another version of GMP everything I can find on the internet. I even tried to install MPIR( but failed due to another unknown reason) and it's still the same.

I know the meaning of the erro and doing the trick of:

```
#define INT_MIN (-2147483647 - 1)
```

is not working. Is GMP library supposed to let us operate outside of that range ?
Is this because I used the Community version of Microsoft Visual C++? If it's not then I don't know what it is. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37546340/1918193 (the error is from Microsoft idiotically turning a bad warning into an error).

Comment: Thank you very much, now I can sleep without frustration.