# Disable #warning for specific include

Tags: c++, suppress-warnings

Is there a way to suppress the warning message thrown by `#warning` from only a specific header file?

```
// file foo.hh
#ifndef FOO_HH
#define FOO_HH

#warning "Foo"

#endif // FOO_HH

// file main.cpp
#include "foo.hh"

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

The target compilers are GCC, Clang and Intel.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: a small [mcve] with source & build command would help.

Comment: If you're using VS then dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159348/disable-single-warning-error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable GCC warnings for a few lines of code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378560/how-to-disable-gcc-warnings-for-a-few-lines-of-code)

Comment: There is no such pre-processor directive `#warning` defined by C++ standard (nor the C standard). When asking about non-standard compiler specific features, you should specify the compiler that you're targetting.

Comment: There is no universal solution for multiple compilers, as warning suppression is inherently compiler-specific. You'll need to abstract the difference using macros or makefiles.

Comment: I understand that there isn't any portable solution but I would like to know how to suppress them in that 3 specific cases. For example, supposing that I want to be compatible with only gcc, what is the way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

For GCC, you can suppress this using:

-Wno-cpp

Comment: I think this is a statement should be asked to GCC team. This is what is written in the man page of gcc:
       -Wno-cpp
           (C, Objective-C, C++, Objective-C++ and Fortran only)

           Suppress warning messages emitted by "#warning" directives.