# How to hide/disable ffmpeg erros when using OpenCV (C++)?

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg

I use OpenCV to read several videos,
but the warning message disturbs me.

My program just reads frames from a video, 
and calculates the MD5 of every frame.

```
string VIDEO::getEndingHash(){
    int idx = 0;
    cv::Mat frame;

    while (1){
        Cap_.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, _FrameCount - idx);
        Cap_ >> frame;

        if (frame.empty())
            idx++;
        else
            break;
    }
    Cap_.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0);

    return MD5::MatMD5(frame);
}
```

How to hide/disable ffmpeg erros when using OpenCV (C++)?
[image]

Comment: You can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159348/disable-single-warning-error

Comment: Thank you, but failed...