# Concise way to disable specific warning instances in Clang

Tags: c++, clang

Suppose there is some warning in my code, e.g. that Clang has added padding to a struct. I am find with that particular instance and I want to mark it as "Noted; don't warn me about this instance again".

Is there a way to do this that isn't insanely verbose (i.e. `#pragma clang diagnostic push` etc)? Ideally something like a comment on the same line as the warning, something like this:

```
// clang(-Wno-padded)
```

To be clear, I only want to suppress *one specific instance* of the warning (which normally requires `#pragma diagnostic push`/`pop`), not all warnings in the file.

Comment: `#pragma` is the way to do it, I am afraid. The compiler is not **allowed** to interpret e.g. a comment the way you outlined, as that would affect fully-conforming programs in a non-standard way.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be allowed to enable or disable *warnings* based on comments. The standard has nothing to say about warnings at all. As long as it never emits an error due to parsing a comment it wouldn't affect compilation at all.

Answer (score 51):

As described in the [Controlling Diagnostics via Pragmas](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-via-pragmas) article it would be:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wpadded"
```

If you want to suppress a warning in a certain chunk of code (be it a single line of code or multiple statements) then you need to utilize the `push` / `pop` mechanism:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wpadded"
// your code for which the warning gets suppressed 
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
// not suppressed here
```

Comment: That does it for everything after that line in the file though. Not what I want. I just want to suppress *one instance* of the warning.

Comment: Ok but I already mentioned this possibility in the question. I wanted a more concise way to do it (I'm pretty sure it is impossible at the moment, but worth asking).

Comment: @Timmmm Unfortunately those are the only available options.

Comment: @Timmmm: As I commented above, `#pragma` is the way reserved by the language standard to allow for implementation-defined behaviour. A comment, for example, **must** be ignored by the compiler, because otherwise the compiler would not be standard-compliant. So you have to do compiler-specific things via `#pragma`.

Comment: Well... sure, but I would be happy with non standard-compliant behaviour.

Comment: @Timmmm For some context, Visual Studio does provide what you're looking for. In fact they provide [both alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25447795).

Comment: Note: I had to use `#pragma GCC` instead of `#pragma clang` to get both the clangd linter and the compiler to work properly with no additional warnings.

Answer (score 10):

If you have some include file where you can put a macro definition like this:

```
#define DO_PRAGMA(x) _Pragma(#x)
#define NOWARN(warnoption, ...)                    \
    DO_PRAGMA(GCC diagnostic push)                 \
    DO_PRAGMA(GCC diagnostic ignored #warnoption)  \
    __VA_ARGS__                                    \
    DO_PRAGMA(GCC diagnostic pop)
```

Then you can disable a warning within your code like this:

```
NOWARN(-Wpadded,
// your code for which the warning gets suppressed 
)
```

Example: https://godbolt.org/z/oW87ej

---

Slightly off-topic note:

gcc does not allow `GCC diagnostic ....` pragmas within expressions. So something like this:

```
#define MY_MYCRO(type) NOWARN(-Wpadded, sizeof(struct{char c; type t;}))
int myval = MY_MYCRO(int);
```

will produce a error in gcc and won't compile. Note: Using `clang diagnostic ....` pragmas will not produce an error in gcc (but also doesn't disable the warning in gcc).