# Is it a problem to have an incorrect "'noreturn' should not return" warning?

Tags: gcc, clang, noreturn

I'M USING NOSTDLIB! So I can't use C's `abort`. In fact I'm implementing a variant of it

I get the following warning in clang

> a.c:12:1: warning: function declared 'noreturn' should not return [-Winvalid-noreturn]

in GCC it says

> a.c:12:1: warning: ‘noreturn’ function does return

Is this a problem or fix-able? It seems like gettid is implicit even though the man pages says it is in unistd.h.

```
#include <signal.h>
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>

#ifndef __clang__
[[noreturn]]
#endif
__attribute__ ((__noreturn__))
void test()
{
        kill(gettid(), SIGABRT);
}

int main() {
        test();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `I'M USING NOSTDLIB` Yet you are using `unistd.h`, which is way bigger than "stdlib". What do you mean by "using nostdlib"? `abort` literally calls raise(SIGABRT) https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdlib/abort.c#L79 , you might as well use it. Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378560/how-to-disable-gcc-warnings-for-a-few-lines-of-code , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48426484/concise-way-to-disable-specific-warning-instances-in-clang answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
__attribute__ ((__noreturn__))
void test(void)
{
        kill(gettid(), SIGABRT);
        __builtin_unreachable();
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you I knew there had to be something