# warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false'

Tags: c++, templates

I have written a template function which takes int32, bool and int16 as an input. 
However for bool, I am getting this warning. Any ideas, how can I resolve it.

```
template<class T>
void GameControl::assignValues(char *gaff, T &output)
{
   output = T(atoi(gaff));
}
```

The function calls are as follows:

```
int32 intout;
assignValues("1234", intout);
bool boolout;
assignValues("1234", boolout);
```

can anyone tell, how to get rid of the warning?

EDIT: 
This worked, but not sure of the consequences. I just suppressed the warning.

```
#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable : 4101)
// Your function
#pragma warning( pop )
```

Comment: Perhaps *specialize* the function for `bool`?

Comment: On an unrelated note, the `atoi` function is usually discouraged, as it's impossible to differ between a valid input `"0"` and an invalid input which results in `0` being returned. I recommend [`std::strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) or [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) instead.

Comment: Why isn't this returning a value, instead of using an output "parameter"? Your code could just read `int23 intout = assignValues("1234");`

Comment: Building on the comment by @juanchopanza, for `bool` it would be `bool boolout = assignValues("1234") != 0;`

Comment: This is just a dummy function I have created for the issue, the original function is already returning a value and is different, but only this functionality is causing the issue. I just want to avoid code duplication

Answer (score 3):

Your first job is to change the function parameter list to a `const char* gaff` since standard C++ does not allow the decay of a `const char[N]` to a `char*`. Ironic it is that your compiler doesn't issue a diagnostic but complains about the dubious cast!

As for that warning, you can force the issue with

```
output = static_cast<T>(atoi(gaff));
```

Most compilers then will assume that you know what you're doing. If you still get a warning, then *specialise* the template function for the `bool` case; a solution which, on balance, I think I prefer (other than the pragmatic approach of switching off the warning for that particular function):

```
template<>
void assignValues(const char *gaff, bool &output)
{
   output = atoi(gaff) != 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but didn't work, getting the same warning

Comment: @YashKapoor: Damn compilers! I've added the specialisation explicitly. Try that.

Comment: Sorry mu bad, I tried only the first part. Specializing I know, I just want to avoid code duplication. This is just a demo function. The real function is a little bigger in size.

Answer (score 0):

You can fully specialize the function template for `bool`:

```
template<>
void GameControl::assignValues<bool>(char *gaff, boot &output)
{
   output = !!atoi(gaff);
}
```

Comment: This does solve the issue, but now there is a duplication of code,  I wanted to avoid that. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by *duplication of code* ? This case is **only** for `T = bool`. For all other values of `T` (e.g.: `int`), your *primary template* is used instead.

Comment: Just in case I modify the functionality of the code in the template function, then I would have copy paste it in the bool module as well. That is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Well, if the other approaches based on casting did still show the warning, I would suggest to individually [suppress that warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159348/disable-single-warning-error) (`C4800`).

Comment: Thanks, I guess that is a better solution. I'll just suppress warning, If it doesn't perform as expected, then I will write a separate function.