# Disable only warning D9024 (unrecognised file type; object file assumed)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, suppress-warnings

I have an OS-agnostic makefile (ugh, I know) which supports both GNU and MSVC compilers (among others). It always generates `.o` object files when compiling, even when compiling for MSVC (which expects `.obj` files). This is not a major problem; `cl` issues warning

```sh
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type '.o', object file assumed
```

and carries on, successfully compiling.

I'd like to remove this unsightly command line warning, and *only* this warning, but can't figure out any way to do it.

Arguments like [IGNORE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/ignore-ignore-specific-warnings?view=vs-2019) don't seem to suppress it, e.g. using

```sh
cl -IGNORE:D9024 ...
```

and techniques (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159348/disable-single-warning-error) one) to suppress warnings generated in-code don't apply for this command line warning.

Is there any way to suppress D9024?

Otherwise (and preferably), is there a way to tell MSVC that the provided `.o` files ARE object files, so that it needn't assume so?

Comment: So it detected that .o is not a *source file* and dealt with it.  You kinda have to admire the wisdom of the ancients.

Comment: If you are also providing cl.exe with the /c option, you should not be sending it object files. Why is it receiving an object file when it thinks it should be getting a source file?

Comment: @0-0 I'm not doing so... The error occurs when linking my `.o` files with `cl`, without the `/c` flag

Comment: @HansPassant I don't understand, this occurs at linking (no source files passed) and this warning does not occur if the object files are named `.obj`

Answer (score 1):

Simplified by performing no linking with `cl`, instead explicitly invoking MSVC's `link`

Comment: Is there a flag to ``CL`` to dump the linker invocation produced by the ``CL`` compler driver (the ``D`` in ``D9024``)?  This would simplify replacing ``CL`` with ``LINK``.