# Force NVCC straight to linking phase

Tags: visual-c++, linker, nvcc, cl

I'm porting a GPU application to Windows, using MSVC, which doesn't seem to play very nice with NVCC. I have separated the compiling and linking phases. `nvcc` will pre-process only the cuda files:

```sh
nvcc -dc -ccbin cl somefile.cu
```

and `cl` will compile everything else:

```sh
cl anotherfile.c
```

This separation was necessary, since many MSVC flags (excluded here) didn't jive with `nvcc`'s wrapping of `cl.exe` (a related symptom [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61175954/nvcc-overriding-a-msvc-flag-ehs)).

With compiling done, there are two ways I can do the linking.

1. use `nvcc` to link *only* the CUDA device code, and then use `link.exe` to link everything, as per [this guide](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/separate-compilation-linking-cuda-device-code/).

As hard as I tried, I could not get `link` to find the CUDA headers, nor could I find any doc about how to point `link` to the `cudart` library. If only it were as easy as their `g++` example!

2. let `nvcc` do all the linking.

According to the [doc](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-altering-compiler-linker-behavior) however, there is "no option" to jump to the linking stage. So when I try to link everything, using...

```sh
nvcc somefile.o anotherfile.o -o app.exe
```

I get some warnings from `cl`!

```sh
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'somefile.o', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'anotherfile.o', object file assumed
```

Naturally, `nvcc` assumes these object files are source code and sends them to `cl`, because the doc includes:

> Note that nvcc does not make any distinction between object, library or resource files.

Of *course* `cl` is complaining - these object files should be passed straight to the linker. I know `link` does eventually get invoked, beause I pass it some unrelated arguments with `-Xlinker`. After these warnings, `app.exe` is indeed compiled.

Despite the doc indicating there is no linker phase argument, how can I force `nvcc` to just *link* the objects, and not incorrectly pass them to `cl`? There is no way to suppress these warnings (at least not without being [condemned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60592976/disable-only-warning-d9024-unrecognised-file-type-object-file-assumed/60607454#60607454) by the stackoverflow community).

Comment: even the [-link](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-specifying-compilation-phase-link) flag specifies to "*compile* and link", woe!

Answer (score -1):

check out my cuda code from http://github.com/fangq/mcx

you can compile it on Windows in Cygwin64/MSYS2 terminal, go to `mcx/src` folder, and type "make", this is what I see

```
nvcc -c -g -lineinfo -Xcompiler -Wall -Xcompiler "/openmp /W0" -DSAVE_DETECTORS -use_fast_math -arch=sm_30 -DMCX_TARGET_NAME='"Fermi MCX"' -DUSE_ATOMIC -use_fast_math -o mcx_core.obj  mcx_core.cu
mcx_core.cu
e:\gitroot\project\github\mcx\src\mcx_core.cu(2042) : warning C4701: potentially uninitialized local variable 'gsrcpattern' used
e:\gitroot\project\github\mcx\src\mcx_core.cu(2042) : warning C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'gsrcpattern' used
nvcc -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I"/lib/include" -c -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -DWIN32 -Xcompiler /openmp -c -o mcx_utils.obj  mcx_utils.c
mcx_utils.c
nvcc -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I"/lib/include" -c -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -DWIN32 -Xcompiler /openmp -c -o mcx_shapes.obj  mcx_shapes.c
mcx_shapes.c
nvcc -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I"/lib/include" -c -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -DWIN32 -Xcompiler /openmp -c -o tictoc.obj  tictoc.c
tictoc.c
nvcc -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I"/lib/include" -c -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -DWIN32 -Xcompiler /openmp -c -o mcextreme.obj  mcextreme.c
mcextreme.c
nvcc -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I"/lib/include" -c -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -DWIN32 -Xcompiler /openmp -c -o cjson/cJSON.obj  cjson/cJSON.c
cJSON.c
nvcc mcx_core.obj mcx_utils.obj mcx_shapes.obj tictoc.obj mcextreme.obj cjson/cJSON.obj -o ../bin/mcx -L"/lib/x64" -lcudart -Xcompiler /openmp
mcx_core.obj
mcx_utils.obj
mcx_shapes.obj
tictoc.obj
mcextreme.obj
cJSON.obj
   Creating library ../bin/mcx.lib and object ../bin/mcx.exp
```

it compiles each c unit, and link .obj files as expected, I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though I'm compiling specifically with MSVC, and asking about separation of compiling and linking (which your build doesn't do)

Comment: No, my commands do separate the compilation from linking (the last command), and nvcc was configured to call msvc for both compiling and linking.

Comment: Ah my apologies - but you don't state how; what differs from my example? Hardly a MWE, but one possibly explanation is that I compile to `.o` files, whereas you use Windows conventional `.obj`. Using `.o` is necessary in my situation

Comment: I don't think the suffix was a problem. I just changed a single line in my makefile (https://github.com/fangq/mcx/blob/master/src/Makefile#L75) from .obj to .o, I was able to compile/link properly on my windows machine (win10, vc12, cuda 8), the only difference is the linker emits a warning `cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'mcx_core.o', object file assumed` , same warning like you saw. but but the binary was created properly.

Comment: alright, re-reading your original post - was your question why linking command was sent to cl? you can find out by adding -v to the last nvcc linking command. From my test, it calls `nvlink` with `-link` to link, but has this line: `cl.exe @"C:\...\tmp/tmpxft_00...-8.res" -Fe"../bin/mcx"` at the end which emits the warnings.

Comment: My question is " How can I force `nvcc` to just link the objects, and not incorrectly pass them to `cl`?"

Comment: then you have to run `nvcc` with `-v` and understand what it does by calling `cl.exe -Fe` in the linking stage.