# QTimer single shot, passing lambda with exception in capture

Tags: c++, qt, lambda, qtimer

I'm using Qt 5.15.0.
I have a try-catch block as follows:

```
try
{
   //some code here
}
catch(std::exception& e)
{
   QTimer::singleShot(0,[e](){ throw e;});
}
```

I get a warning treated as an error C4702: QtCore\qobjectdefs_impl.h(146): warning C4702: unreachable code.
Any idea what's going wrong?
Removing the e from the capture and leaving the lambda empty fixes the problem, so looks like it's something related to that? Thank you

Comment: use try-except inside lambda

Comment: @eyllanesc but I wanna be able to forward the exception to another handler. How will that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically noise and you can ignore that warning. It comes from how Qt wraps your functor. The code [around the error location](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.15.0/src/corelib/kernel/qobjectdefs_impl.h#L146) looks as follows:

```
template <typename, typename, typename, typename> struct FunctorCall;
template <int... II, typename... SignalArgs, typename R, typename Function>
struct FunctorCall<IndexesList<II...>, List<SignalArgs...>, R, Function> {
    static void call(Function &f, void **arg) {
        f((*reinterpret_cast<typename RemoveRef<SignalArgs>::Type *>(arg[II+1]))...), ApplyReturnValue<R>(arg[0]);
    }
};
```

The compiler is complaining that the `ApplyReturnValue<R>(arg[0])` expression won't be executed. It's a valid complaint, but that code does not have to run, so there's nothing to worry about, because in your case `ApplyReturnValue<R>` is really `ApplyReturnValue<void>` since the lambda has no return value, and thus [the overridden `operator,` does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7159392/1329652):

```
template<typename T>
    void operator,(T, const ApplyReturnValue<void> &) {}
```

So you can [selectively disable that warning for that bit of code only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7159392/1329652), ie.:

```
try
{
   // some code here
}
catch(std::exception& e)
{
   #pragma warning(push)
   #pragma warning(disable : 4702)
   QTimer::singleShot(0,[e](){ throw e;});
   #pragma warning(pop)
}
```

And also, if you know that the thread you're running on is the main thread, you could use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(qApp, [e]{ throw e; }, Qt::QueuedConnection);` instead of the zero timer, although admittedly it's more text, so I guess it's up to one's preference without a clearly better syntax.