# Type Cast Truncation from HANDLE to ULONG C++

Tags: c++, type-conversion, kernel, driver

I am getting the warning (treated as error):

> Type Cast Pointer Truncation from HANDLE to ULONG

When I try to compile, I understand that the type has a different length as I am compiling ARM64 rather than ARM, therefore I need to change the type or `static_cast` it, however I receive errors such as "expected (" when changing the line to something like this:

```cpp
return static_cast<ULONG>PsGetProcessId(current_process); //this gives me invalid conversion type as 
                                                          //there are no brackets around the static cast 
                                                          //because I am returning its value
```

I add brackets, however there is always a problem and it never seems to work, always "Expected (":

```cpp
return (static_cast<ULONG>)PsGetProcessId(current_process); //this bracket error
```

ORIGINAL CODE BELOW

```cpp
ULONG memory::get_process_id_by_name(PEPROCESS start_process, const char* process_name)
{
    PLIST_ENTRY active_process_links;
    PEPROCESS current_process = start_process;

    do
    {
        PKPROCESS kproc = (PKPROCESS)current_process;
        PDISPATCHER_HEADER header = (PDISPATCHER_HEADER)kproc;
        LPSTR current_process_name = (LPSTR)((PUCHAR)current_process + IMAGE_FILE_NAME);

        if (header->SignalState == 0 && strcmp(current_process_name, process_name) == 0)
        {   
            return (ULONG)PsGetProcessId(current_process); //warning occurs here
        }

        active_process_links = (PLIST_ENTRY)((PUCHAR)current_process + ACTIVE_PROCESS_LINKS_FLINK);
        current_process = (PEPROCESS)(active_process_links->Flink);
        current_process = (PEPROCESS)((PUCHAR)current_process - ACTIVE_PROCESS_LINKS_FLINK);

    } while (start_process != current_process);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HANDLE` type is used to point to an opaque structure.

It usually stores an index value, but in the `winnt.h` header file, it is defined as a pointer-length type.

```
typedef void *HANDLE;
```

So the correct approach is to treat the process id as a pointer-length type as well.

I know you don't like `HANDLE`, so you can use `ULONG_PTR`, it has the same length as the pointer type.

Here is the fixed code:

```
ULONG_PTR memory::get_process_id_by_name(PEPROCESS start_process, const char* process_name)
{
    PLIST_ENTRY active_process_links;
    PEPROCESS current_process = start_process;

    do
    {
        PKPROCESS kproc = (PKPROCESS)current_process;
        PDISPATCHER_HEADER header = (PDISPATCHER_HEADER)kproc;
        LPSTR current_process_name = (LPSTR)((PUCHAR)current_process + IMAGE_FILE_NAME);

        if (header->SignalState == 0 && strcmp(current_process_name, process_name) == 0)
        {
            return (ULONG_PTR)PsGetProcessId(current_process);
        }

        active_process_links = (PLIST_ENTRY)((PUCHAR)current_process + ACTIVE_PROCESS_LINKS_FLINK);
        current_process = (PEPROCESS)(active_process_links->Flink);
        current_process = (PEPROCESS)((PUCHAR)current_process - ACTIVE_PROCESS_LINKS_FLINK);

    } while (start_process != current_process);

    return 0;
}
```

If you have to use `ULONG` for other reasons, you can refer to @SoronelHaetir's solution.

---

Example for comment:

**Before**:

```
void test()
{
    ULONG value = (ULONG_PTR)0xFFFFFFFFFFFF;
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(value);
}

EXTERN_C NTSTATUS DriverEntry(DRIVER_OBJECT *pDriverObject, UNICODE_STRING *pRegistryPath)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pDriverObject);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pRegistryPath);
    test();
    return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
}
```

Warnings:

```
error C2220: the following warning is treated as an error
warning C4305: 'initializing': truncation from 'ULONG_PTR' to 'ULONG'
warning C4309: 'initializing': truncation of constant value
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

**After**:

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4305)
#pragma warning(disable: 4309)
void test()
{
    ULONG value = (ULONG_PTR)0xFFFFFFFFFFFF;
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(value);
}
#pragma warning(pop)

EXTERN_C NTSTATUS DriverEntry(DRIVER_OBJECT *pDriverObject, UNICODE_STRING *pRegistryPath)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pDriverObject);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pRegistryPath);
    test();
    return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
}
```

No warnings:

```
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply!
When following your solution, I get the error: 
'=': conversion from 'ULONG_PTR' to 'ULONG', possible loss of data

In a different file of my driver. Please see the post below for code causing error.

Comment: if (ioctl == NF_GET_PROCESS_ID)
 {
  PNF_PROCESS_ID_REQUEST process_id_request = (PNF_PROCESS_ID_REQUEST)irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;
  process_id_request->process_id = memory::get_process_id_by_name(IoGetCurrentProcess(), process_id_request->process_name);
  if (process_id_request->process_id) { status = STATUS_SUCCESS; }
  bytes_io = sizeof(NF_PROCESS_ID_REQUEST);
  DbgPrintEx(0, 0, " NF_GET_PROCESS_ID\n");
 }

Comment: @TheManTheGuy69 You can just disable that warning [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7159392/13433323).

Comment: unfortunately I cannot disable the warning as I am working on a kernel driver.

Comment: @TheManTheGuy69 I tested that it works fine (yes, kernel driver), and with `#pragma warning(push)` and `#pragma warning(pop)` you can disable specific warnings only for that function, not globally.

Comment: @TheManTheGuy69 I would recommend that you just change the type of `process_id_request->process_id` to ULONG_PTR, if possible (this will break ABI compatibility).

Comment: Thank you so much I forgot the push and pop. Everything working now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use ULONG_PTR instead of ULONG:

```
static_cast<ULONG_PTR>(hHandle)
```

If the value the handle holds is actually meant to be used as a ULONG then cast the ULONG_PTR to ULONG:

```
static_cast<ULONG>(static_cast<ULONG_PTR>(hHandle))
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the fast reply, however I run into another problem when using the solution.
```
return static_cast<ULONG>(static_cast<ULONG_PTR>(PsGetProcessId(current_process)));
```
I get the error:
'static_cast': cannot convert from 'HANDLE' to 'ULONG_PTR'

Do you have any idea how to fix? This problem persists for both solutions you have offered