Incorrect warning C4702: unreachable code?
I am currently working on the following function:
int cuda_device_count = 0;
bool cuda_enabled = true;
char devname[256];
// logger_spd is an spdlog::logger with file sink

...

void InitCuda()
{
    // This function call returns 0 if there are no CUDA capable devices.
    cudaError_t cr = cudaGetDeviceCount(&cuda_device_count);

    if (cr != cudaSuccess)
    {
        std::string msg = std::string("[InitCuda] Failed retrieve number of CUDA devices: ") + std::string(cudaGetErrorString(cr));
        throw std::exception(msg.c_str());
    }

    if (cuda_device_count == 0)
    {
        cuda_enabled = false;
        logger_spd->warn("CUDA device not found. Disabling CUDA processing");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        std::string msg = "Found " + std::to_string(cuda_device_count) + " CUDA capable device(s)";
        logger_spd->info(msg);
    }

    // Get CUDA device properties
    cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;

    for (int dev = 0; dev < cuda_device_count; ++dev) {
        cr = cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, dev);
        strcpy_s(devname, deviceProp.name);

        std::string msg = "CUDA GPU " + std::to_string(dev) + " \"" + std::string(devname) + "\" : [BusID " + std::to_string(deviceProp.pciBusID) + " | DevID " + std::to_string(deviceProp.pciDeviceID) + "]";
        logger_spd->info(msg);

        if (cr != cudaSuccess)
        {
            msg = std::string("[InitCuda] Failed to retrieve properties of CUDA device: ") + std::string(cudaGetErrorString(cr));
            throw std::exception(msg.c_str());
        }

        break;
    }
}

Note: The break at the end of the for loop. Since it's still work in progress, I am currently breaking the loop after the first successful discovery of a CUDA device.
The function is working perfectly fine in another project where warnings are not treated as errors.
In VS Studio 2019 I am getting

1>C:...\SceneCapture.cpp(323): error C2220: the following warning is treated as an error
1>C:...\SceneCapture.cpp(323): warning C4702: unreachable code

at the location of the for loop and I don't know why.

The first if - I throw an exception in case querying the CUDA devices on my machine fails. In this case the function is interrupted and the exception is caught one level up where InitCuda() is called
The second if - while initialized to 0, cuda_device_count is passed onto cudaGetDeviceCount(), which - if successful - will return 0 or higher. In case of 0 I just toggle cuda_enabled to false, log a warning message and go back one level up. Otherwise (the else) I just log success with the number of CUDA devices found (>1)

When the for loop is reached, I have at least one iteration step due to cuda_device_count >= 1. But even if that was not the case, the code should still be reachable so it doesn't matter if the loop runs even once. Note that, if I remove the for loop, the warning disappears.

Probably because you either throw or break in the first iteration and therefore never reach the increment.

VS 2022 will explain its reasoning if you click on a warning, I forget whether 2019 has that.  It's a popup listing a sequence of steps like "assume foo false in line 173  if (foo) { }, assume bar false in line 215 if (foo && bar) ..."

@fdan Indeed. After removing the break it no longer complains. However, how would I tackle this? As I've stated it's currently WIP. I plan on adding support for storing all queries devices and then evaluate them based on performance, picking the best one. But until than it would be helpful to break after the first found. I guess I can simply remove the for loop for now as an alternative solution.

@rbaleksandar just replace the for-loop with an if-statement while prototyping, like if cuda_device_count > 0. That's technically what's happening right now

@DaveS I assume you mean the popup balloon similar to the one when an uncaught exception is thrown? I don't see any popup regarding my problem in VS 2019. If I know the name of the feature, perhaps I can look for it and enable it.

The function is working perfectly fine in another project where warnings are not treated as errors - No, it's not. It's working exactly the same way. You're just choosing to bury your head in the sand in the other project.

"But until than it would be helpful to break after the first found. I guess I can simply remove the for loop for now as an alternative solution.": I don't use MSVC myself, but it surely has a mechanism to suppress individual warnings on a line-by-line basis. Add this to the for loop until it is finished. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159348/disable-single-warning-error.

Please provide a [mcve], for a start.

BTW, in any case, you're not finished with that code, so why not simply ignore the warning for now?

You could try to cheat the compiler by adding something that makes the break conditional, but the compiler won't see it as constant. However, that's generally a bad idea. If you want to keep the code, either put an #if 0...#endif around it to just remove it, or add a #pragma or whatever the compiler uses to disable the particular warning for this code block.

"@DaveS I assume you mean the popup balloon similar to the one when an uncaught exception is thrown? " -- this is in the IDE when a program is not running.  The Errors widget that has separate views for Errors, Warnings, Messages.  The grid for errors and warnings has a last column "Details" with an icon to click on that pops up a Problem Details list of lines / code that produces the warning.

Your for loop always exits in the first loop iteration, either by throw or by break;.
Therefore the ++dev increment is unreachable code (and it doesn't make sense for there to be a loop to begin with).
Do you really want to throw on the first failing device in that loop rather than trying all the other ones first? Or maybe you want none of them failing. In that case, why is there a break;?

Please edit (the questions about the break are explained in my edit of my question) so that I can accept your answer. Also read the comments below my question.
