# XCode: Getting rid of warning "Unknown escape sequence \+"

Tags: xcode, escaping, warnings

In my code I make extensive use of regular expression, and my patterns look something like this

```
regexp = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@".*?\\\+.*?\\\+.*?\\\+.*?\\\+.*?\\\+.*?\\\+" options:0 error:nil];
```

For the escape sequences I get compiler warnings like "Unknown escape sequence +" which is extremely annoying because it is not wrong in my case. How can I get rid of this warning?

Comment: There is no way except to disable all warnings (or use an escape sequence that doesnt cause a compiler warning).

Comment: @chown This is not true. See Pragma warning push/pop syntax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193476/is-using-pragma-warning-push-pop-the-right-way-to-temporarily-alter-warning-lev

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to many back-slash characters, use:

```
regexp = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@".*?\\+.*?\\+.*?\\+.*?\\+.*?\\+.*?\\+" options:0 error:nil];
```

To get a `\` in a string it needs to be escaped: `\\`. So `\\\+` applies the first `\` to escaping the second `\` and the third `\` tries to escape the plus sign `+` which is an illegal escape.