# How to disable specific warning in VS 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I try to disable a warning with the following pragma

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
                std::copy(std::begin(l), std::end(l), _begin);
#pragma warning(pop)
```

Here, `_begin` is a pointer. But i continue to get the warning.

I can disable the warning in property pages, but i want to suppress it in a smallest possible scope.

EDIT:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int i1[10];
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
    copy((int*)i1, (int*)i1+10, (int*)i1);
#pragma warning(pop)

    return 0;
}
```

Results in:

> warning C4996: 'std::copy::_Unchecked_iterators::_Deprecate': Call to 'std::copy' with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'

Comment: Could you make a minimal and reproducible example out of this snippet?

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/18461418/1597714?

Comment: remove space in pragma after :