# Problem in defining of Vector class Copy Constructor (C++)

Tags: c++, vector, copy-constructor

I tried to define a `Vector` class and some functions of it manually. Everything seemed like okay, until I wrote the copy constructor, where I get a warning in this part of the loop:

```
this->arr[i] = vec.arr[i];
C6386:Buffer overrun while writing to 'this->arr'
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vector {
private:
    int size, capacity;
    int* arr;

public:
    Vector(int _capacity = 5) : capacity(_capacity) {
        size = 0;
        arr = new int[capacity];
        cout << "constructor" << endl;
    }
    ~Vector() {
        delete[] arr;
        cout << "destructor" << endl;
    }
    Vector(const Vector& vec) {
        this->capacity = vec.capacity;
        this->size = vec.size;
        this->arr = new int[this->capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            this->arr[i] = vec.arr[i]; //WARNING. C6386:Buffer overrun while                     writing to 'this->arr'
        }
        cout << "copy constructor" << endl;
    }
    void push_back(int n) {
        if (size==capacity) {
            resize();
        }
        arr[size] = n;
        size++;

    }
    void resize() {
        int* tmp = new int[capacity*=2];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            tmp[i] = arr[i];
        }
        delete[] arr;
        arr = tmp;
    }
    int Size() { return size; }
};


int main() {
    Vector V1(3);
    V1.push_back(1);
    
    cout << V1.Size();
    V1.push_back(4);
    cout << V1.Size() << endl;
    V1.push_back(4);
    cout << V1.Size() << endl;
    V1.push_back(4);
    cout << V1.Size() << endl;

    Vector V2(V1);

    return 0;
}
```

I thought the problem is that I'm not careful enough and I maybe let the loop get out of the bounds somewhere, but it seems like that is okay.

Can you please help me to define the problem?

Comment: You failed to implement the `Vector` user-defined assignment operator.  Thus any code that uses your class that makes copies of `Vector` will be flawed.  [What is the rule of 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The question asks about a problem in copy constructor implementation. I'd say it's fair to assume that copy assignment operator would be implemented *after* you have working copy constructor rather than trying to implement both and failing at both.

Comment: you miss to delete the old array, but otherwise it looks like a false positive

Comment: @OP: I can't reproduce the warning with the code you provided: https://godbolt.org/z/3MvhG75oG. Common checklist: are you sure you saved all files that are compiled and you are compiling the exact code you've shown? How do you compile the code?

Comment: wasnt able to reproduce it either https://godbolt.org/z/hvsYoMf7e

Comment: Checked with asan, then with valgrind, can't reproduce.

Comment: Brothers and sisters, the program works properly, the only problem is with that warning

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai There's no old array in a constructor.

Comment: This looks like a false positive from Visual C++, possibly because it can't tell that `size <= capacity`.

Comment: @molbdnilo you were right, when I added "if" which checked size<=capacity condition it worked. Is there a better way to avoid it?

Comment: @SamvelMuqelyan *Is there a better way to avoid it?* -- Try `std::copy(vec.arr, vec.arr + size, arr);` instead of the `for` loop.

Comment: You are `new`ing `arr` with `capacity` but indexing it upto `size-1`. There's no proof that `size==capacity`. Either call `new` with `size` or assert `size<=capacity`, so the compiler can prove validity of used indices.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does; `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: Since this warning is specific to MSVC++, you can turn it off by `#pragma warning`. See [this SO post with lots of options for its usage, both MS-specific and portable.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193476/is-using-pragma-warning-push-pop-the-right-way-to-temporarily-alter-warning-lev)

Comment: your code looks fine, I bet the VS analytical tool is not accurate